# using lua in kobold2d to control parameters

Tags: cocos2d, lua

Is there a tutorial on using LUA in Kobold2d?

I want to know if its possible to use it to control the game behavior (like max speed decrease of timer, and bonus points) by uploading a new script to the app.

I found this link in the FAQ:

http://www.kobold2d.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=917888

but it does not mention if I can replace the lua script from within the game, and reload it, is that possible?  Should i just have a parameter file instead that i can download and replace?

Answer (score 1):

From [that page you linked to](http://www.kobold2d.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=917888) (emphasis mine):

> Kobold2D does not provide a Lua scripting interface for game engine classes, eg **you can't script game logic in Lua**. What you can do is to edit your game's parameters in Lua, then read them in with just one line of code.

Max speed, timers and bonus points are all *game logic*. That same page goes into detail on why exactly you shouldn't try to do this.

The documentation recommends [Corona SDK](http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/) as a similar framework if you like Lua.

Comment: Thank you!  I have not used corona, but appreciate the clarity on why you should not use LUA.